# Find the minimum norm least squares solution of Ax = b using QR factorization when A \in R^(m×n) is not full rank

Tags: math, least-squares, proof

I can only solve this when A is full rank. The solution will be R^(-1)*Q^(T)*b 
And when rank(A) = r < n, then the QR factorization will be A = [Q_1 Q_2] [R_1 R_2, 0 0] 
I don't know how to move forward, please help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is really better-suited for programming questions. For math questions, I suggest https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Note it's unclear whether you're asking about how to solve this problem by hand, or with a computer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I'm trying to solve it by hand.
As I mentioned, the first question is when rank(A) = n. This can be easily solved by just deriving the least square solution first. x^(tilde)=(A^(T)*A)^(-1)*A^(T)*b then just used A = QR. 
For rank(A) = r < n, I can't seem to do it that way, or am I wrong. Please show me the way.
I am sorry for my poor math writing.

Comment: I posted the same question here. Please help.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442815/find-the-minimum-norm-least-squares-solution-of-ax-b-using-qr-factorization-wh

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.